# How to add value into sub-list

Tags: python

Looking for a way to add value **555** right after **6000** to make it and display it.

```
mylist = [4, 11, [300, 400, [5000, 6000, 555], 500], 30, 40]
```

***Original list below.***

```
mylist = [4, 11, [300, 400, [5000, 6000], 500], 30, 40]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try adding append to corresponding index
`mylist[2][2].append(555)`